# how can i create mini photo while creating photo?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have a photo upload service on django.
when i add a photo I want it to add one more photo with 50% split.
If I put it in the pre_save on my photo save service, it can't find the photo (because it's not actually on the server) If I add it to the post_save, it goes into loop and adds unlimited

when I add a photo (postman or etc.) How can get to save a small photo at a time?.

here is my model

```py
class UserPhoto(General, Status):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User Id", related_name='UserPhoto_user',
                             null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    mini_link = models.ImageField(upload_to='mini_photos', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_photos'
```

my view

```py
class UserPhoto(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Photo.objects.get(user__user__pk=pk)
        except Exception as e:
            return e

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            photo = self.get_object(request.user.pk)
            serializer = UserPhotoSerializer(photo)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserPhotoSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def put(self, request):
        photo = self.get_object(request.user.pk)
        serializer = UserPhotoSerializer(photo, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my serializer

```py
class UserPhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPhoto
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["user"] = self.context['request'].user.User_userbase
        return UserPhoto.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

my signal

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=UserPhoto)
    def create_mini_photo(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    blob = BytesIO()
    path = instance.link.path
    image = Image.open(path)
    width, height = image.size
    resized_image = image.resize((int(width / 2), int(height / 2)))
    resized_image = resized_image.convert('RGB')
    resized_image.save(blob, 'JPEG')
    instance.mini_link.save(str(instance.link), File(blob), save=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand there is status in the user photo model, when you add a new one, you will deactivate the old data and create a new record.

Therefore, you can first update the create method on the serializer as follows;

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
       validated_data["user"] = self.context['request'].user.User_userbase
       validated_data["status"] = "Active"
       photos = UserPhoto.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user.User_userbase, status="Active")
       if len(photos) > 0:
          for photo_obj in photos:
               photo_obj.status = "Passive"
               photo_obj.save()
       return UserPhoto.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

After making this update, you can make the codes work only on the new record by using the **created** parameter in the signal. Thus, after uploading the real photo, a new recording will be created and the inside of the signal will work, and when recording the 50% reduced photo, it will not work because there is no new recording. The important point here is that you use post_save because the photo must be saved. Example;

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=UserPhoto)
def create_mini_photo(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
       blob = BytesIO()
       path = instance.link.path
       image = Image.open(path)
       width, height = image.size
       resized_image = image.resize((int(width / 2), int(height / 2)))
       resized_image = resized_image.convert('RGB')
       resized_image.save(blob, 'JPEG')
       instance.mini_link.save(str(instance.link), File(blob), save=False)
```